# python's re: find words beginning from "string" in any case

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to make a regex, that will return list words that begin with `barbar` in any case. It must return not the whole word, but only matching part. For example, from string

```
string = u'baRbarus, semibarbarus: qui BARbari sunt, alteres BARBARos non sequuntur!'
# output is...
>>> ['baRbar', 'BARbar', 'BARBAR']
```

I've tried such code:

```
re.compile(ur"([\A\b]*)(barbar)", re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE).findall(string)
# it returns...
[(u'', u'baRbar'), (u'', u'barbar'), (u'', u'BARbar'), (u'', u'BARBAR')]
```

It seems that I missunderstood something. Could you help me, please? And it will be also great if you advice some good tutorials about `re` module. It's too hard to understand `re` from default Python's documentation. Thanks!

Comment: What -- exactly -- is wrong?  What don't you like about the results.  They appear to contain "not the whole word, but only matching part."  What problem do you have?

Comment: I find using `re.findall` much easier than the others.

Comment: 1. Words returned not as list.

Comment: 2. Word "semibarbarus" must be excluded.

Comment: Please don't add comments to your question.  If there are two problems, then please **update** the question to state what the two problems are and then remove the confusing and hard-to-read comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex is sufficient for what you want to do (as long as flags are set):

```
\bbarbar
```

Example:

```
>>> s = u'baRbarus, semibarbarus: qui BARbari sunt, alteres BARBARos non sequuntur!'
>>> re.findall(r'\bbarbar', s, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
[u'baRbar', u'BARbar', u'BARBAR']
```

Here are some comments on your current regex which may clarify why `\bbarbar` does the job:

- `[\A\b]` - `\A` is normally the start of string, and `\b` is word boundary, but inside of a character class `\b` becomes a backspace and I'm not really sure what `\A` becomes
- `[\A\b]*` - This is why your regex matched 'semibarbarus', the `*` means 0 or more so it doesn't require that portion to match, if you dropped the `*` and fixed the above problem it would work
- `([\A\b]*)(barbar)` - Multiple groups mean that `re.findall()` will return a tuple of the groups, rather than just the portion you are interested in

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a very definitive answer, and I've understood my mistake.

Comment: Inside a character class, `\b` is a backspace, and `\A` should match `A` but doesn't seem to match anything.

Comment: @JohnMachin - Good point! The no anchors in character class thing seems obvious when I stop to think about it but I had forgotten.

Comment: I've reported the bug; see my "answer".

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

```
string = 'baRbarus, semibarbarus: qui BARbari sunt, alteres BARBARos non sequuntur!'

l=re.findall(' barbar.+? |^barbar.+? ', string, re.IGNORECASE)
print l
```

Comment: I must save case of words that were found.

Comment: Fixed it so it ignores case and gets the rest of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to have only the words beginning with barbar you have to split the string before. So you should do something like this:

```
def findBarbarus(my_string):
  result = []
  for s in my_string.split(" "):
    result += re.compile(ur"(^barbar)", re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE).findall(s)
  return result
```

The `^` in the regular expression means, that the word must begin with barbar.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: If you use `\A` inside a character class e.g. `r"[\A]"`, it should be treated like a literal A. However it is silently ignored. The same happens with `\B` and `\Z`.

I have [reported](http://bugs.python.org/issue13899) the bug.